# Wavenumber $k$ becoming a continuous variable as $\lambda \to \infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I'm trying to piece together how to get to derive the Fourier transform from the Fourier series, reading my lecturer's notes.

> Now, if $f(x)$ happens to *not* be periodic, we
>   can still give a complete description of $f(x)$ in terms of sines and
>   cosines, but we'd need to sum over a continuum of
>   $k$-values,    instead of  just    integer multiples   of  a   fundamental harmonic.       We  can think   of  a   non-periodic    function    as  the limiting    case    of  a   periodic    one,    where   the wavelength  $\lambda$  tends   to  infinity,   meaning the $k_{n}$'s    become  more    and more    closely spaced  together    until   they    form    a   continuum.
>   In    the limit   $k \to \infty$, the wavenumber $k$ becomes a continuous variable and the summation goes over to an integral: $$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}C_n \ e^{ik_n x} \to \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}C(k)\ e^{ikx}\ dk$$

In my mind, it makes sense that a periodic function ceases to be periodic if its wavelength is infinite, I thinik that's obvious. However, that does *not* make it obvious to me that the wavenumber is continuous. As the wavelength gets larger and larger, the wavenumber gets smaller and smaller, however it is always some value. If I took a graph of a sine wave from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and blew it up so its wavelength got more and more massive, its wavenumber would always have some single value. Is this because we're taking it in the case of an infinite wavelength? I could see how this could maybe make $k$ continuous, but I couldn't justify it well for myself.

Secondly, why are we using the case of a non-periodic function to make the transition from infinite summation to integral for the Fourier transform derivation? What if we're making the derivation for a periodic function? Could we still make this step?